# Test for checking object values inside class

Tags: java, javafx, junit, mockito

I have a javafx application which has a few fields, like an anchorPane. In its .fxml file, that anchorPane [has a few fields like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FZFX.png)

How can I test these values? I'm sure that JUnit can test object values, so I was wondering if I can make something like

```
Assertions.assertThat(mainAnchorPane.getId()).isEqualTo("mainAnchorPane");
```

Not sure but that might be as simple as instantiating an entity class (lets name it Person) and do something like

```
Person person = new Person("Maria");
Assertions.assertThat(person.getName()).isEqualTo("Maria");
```

The point here is that I'm not sure how can I inject the object values from my class into the tests, assuring that Person (or AnchorPane) from my class has the same values in my test.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear (at least, not to me) what you're asking. Specifically I don't really understand what *"how can I inject the object values from my class into the tests"* means. Can you create and post a [mre] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Also, don't post images of code, for [all the obvious reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Post the code as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already thought about this, but there is a test library called TestFX. It is made to test JavaFX applications easily. Maybe it can help you:
https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/

For example you can proof the input of textfields or simulate mouse clicks. You can find more information on the given url.

Comment: That was my very first alternative, but TestFX is designed for creating and testing JavaFX components without a GUI (which is exactly what I'm primarily looking for), although it does not inject the components from my class into the tests.